# Objectify loads object behind Ref<?> even when @Load is not specified

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I have an account object which references a user object.

```
@Cache
@Entity
public final class Account {

    @Id Long id;
    @Index private Ref<User> user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user.get();
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = Ref.create(user);
    }

}
```

I have hidden the Ref as recommended here: http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities - please note the Ref does *not* have the @Load annotation.

When I call my Google Cloud Endpoint from an Android client, it looks like Objectify delivers the account object with the embedded user, even though @Load is not specified.

```
@ApiMethod(name = "account.get")
public Account getAccount(
        @Named("id") final Long id
) {
    return ofy().load().type(Account.class).id(id).now();
}
```

When I query the account directly using Apis Explorer, I also get both, account with the user embedded:

```
200 OK
{ 
"id": "5079604133888000", 
"user": {  "id": "5723348596162560",  
"version": "1402003195251",  
"firstName": "Karl" }, 
"kind": "api#accountItem", 
"etag": "\"30khohwUBSGWr00rYOZuF9f4BTE/Q31EvnQCQ6E9c5YXKEZHNsD_mlQ\""}
```

This raises three questions:

1. Does Appengine always return embedded Refs natively and does Objectify always pass on objects which it already knows?
2. What exactly is @Load for and is there a way to control this behavior? Load Groups?
3. Have I missed something? Why isn't @Load obeyed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your example code, you are not specifying `@Load` which means that loading the account will not fetch the `User`. However, your `@ApiMethod` is serializing the account back to the client, so the `user` property is been accessed, thus a separate fetch is issued to load the user object. That's why you are getting the information of the user when calling the method.

Not specifying `@Load` doesn't mean that you won't get a `User` back. It means that you are not going to retrieve a `User` unless you specifically ask for it later.

Ref works like this:

- I'm a reference, so by default I won't fetch the data.
- If you ask for me, then I will first load the data, then answer you.
- Oh, if you tell me to `@Load` myself, then I will fetch the data initially and have it ready for you.

So this is working fine in your code... but then your `@ApiMethod` is serializing your `Account` object back to the client. The serialization process is going through every property in your `Account` object, including the `user` property. At this point, the `Ref<User>` is being accessed, so the data will get fetched from the Datastore and then returned to the client.

This is making your code very inefficient, since the `Account` objects are loaded without the `User` information, but then you always access the `User` info later (during serialization), issuing a separate fetch. Batching `gets` from the Datastore is way more efficient than issuing separate `gets`.

In your case, you can do either of two things:

1. Add `@Load` to the user property, so the `Account` object is fetched efficiently.
2. Make your `@ApiMethod` return a different `Account` object without the `user` property (thus avoiding fetching the user if you don't need it).

Option 2 above is quite useful since you can abstract your internal Datastore structure from what the client sees. You'll find yourself using this patter quite often.

Comment: Thank you @svpino for your very detailed answer and I believe this is **very important for everybody who's using objectify with REST**. It wasn't clear to me that even though I don't explicitly access the Ref <> from my code, the serializer does so.

Comment: What if I explicitly set the user object as null before sending to client ?